# Como converter textos html (entidades) em textos "normais"?

Tags: php, html

No meu banco de dados está salvo linhas que são "lidas" pelo html, então estão salvas com tags e esses caracteres que não sei o nome => `&nbsp, &eacute` etc..

o problema é que em minha aplicação irei usar esse texto para colocar em um arquivo. só que o texto está indo com tags e esses caracteres.

como eu TRADUZO isso `&nbsp respons&aacute;vel pela integra&ccedil` para isso:
 responsável pela integração

existe alguma função pra isso? estou utilizando php.

ja tentei `utf8_encode()` e `strip_tags ()` pra tags `strip_tags ()` funcionou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a função [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) para converter os entities html nos repectivos caracteres.

```
echo html_entity_decode('respons&aacute;vel');
```

Saída:

```
responsável
```

Comment: `utf8_decode()` também funcionou nesse caso, sabe dizer qual a diferença?

Comment: @Dobrychtop bem curioso mesmo. Estou pesquisando aqui se quiser pode criar uma nova pergunta.